# Navigation drawer icon arrow instead of three lines

Tags: android, icons, navigation-drawer

I have created a new project in eclipse with the navigation drawer and instead of the three lines icon on the top left of the screen I have the back arrow icon. I have found nothing on stack over flow which seems to help.
I have tried to change the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` and `setHomeButtonEnabled` but it does not help
here is a part of the code (by the way its the default code from eclipse)
any one have and idea?
 [image]

Comment: Please check the icon, it might as well not be the three lines icon that you want, replace the icon properly. Also check in your code where from exactly that back icon seems to come

Comment: i have checked the icon and its a 3 lines and in all resolutions folders

Comment: guys if you dont have the answer just do not reply as i told you i searched about 20 different topics on stackoverflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can try setting custom activity back button to Hamburger button.

Here is the code.

So you can change it programmatically easily by using homeAsUpIndicator() function that added in android API level 18 and upper.

```
ActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

If you use support library

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change your styles.xml file to replace the navigation drawer icon adding this code:

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
```

The ic_drawer icon (which you'll put in drawable folder) can be downloaded on the web.

Comment: One note: these <item> tags should be added as children of <style> tag.

Answer (score 1):

To sync the state of the drawer indicator/affordance with the linked DrawerLayout just add code below to your activity

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```